# how to clear a textbox with calendar extender in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, textbox, calendarextender

i have a textbox associated with a calendar extender and a masked edit extender in a asp.net 3.5 project. i would like to clear the texbox when OnBlur...i have tried using the code below but it not working! any ideas guy?

```
document.getElementById('txtDtTo').value ="";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reported problems with the OnBlur event firing, the code to clear the text box looks fine. Why do you need it empty when it loses focus? You could use the OnChange event instead however if I understand your proposed logic correctly you'll always have an empty text box!

Comment: i'm comparing the textbox with another textbox, so when the condition return false, the textbox shoud be clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#<%= txtDtTo.ClientID %>').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtDtTo.ClientID%>").value ="";
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Clear-Selected-Date-of-ASPNet-AJAX-CalendarExtender-using-JavaScript.aspx

```
<ajax:CalendarExtender Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                       ID="txtBillDate_CalendarExtender" 
                       BehaviorID = "txtBillDate_CalendarExtender"
                       OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate"
                       TargetControlID="txtBillDate" 
                       runat="server">
</ajax:CalendarExtender>

function checkDate(sender, args) {
    if (sender._selectedDate > new Date()) {
        showAutoCloseMessage('You cannot select a future date! ', 'warning');
        $find("txtBillDate_CalendarExtender").set_selectedDate(null);
        $("[id*=txtBillDate_CalendarExtender]").val("");
        $(".ajax__calendar_active").removeClass("ajax__calendar_active");
        return false;
    }
}
```